Why has Lebanon kept quiet about recent Israeli incursions across its southern border?
The IDF recently announced that it had been carrying out cross border operations for the last few months accompanied by the release of footage of tunnels and supply bunkers being blown up. This was news to anyone who relies on western new agencies to keep up-to-date.
Why has Lebanon / Hezbollah not being publicizing these raids? In most modern conflicts, the belligerents like to emphasise enemy attacks to help justify their own actions as defensive or retaliatory. So why haven't the Lebanese authorities been hyping-up these incidents?
I can understand the IDF keeping quiet, by why the other side? Could it be that the operations were too small for the Lebanese government to notice? Or too trivial to bother about? Or maybe too embarrassing to mention if the IDF was doing this routinely and getting away with it?
Update for those voting to close. I am not referring to the 'official' ground operating starting 1st and 2nd of October. I'm talking about the last 3 months of covert IDF operations that they have only just revealed to have been going on since August.

I have no specific answer to the question, but another possibility beyond what you list is that calling attention to it would also call attention to all the rockets being fired by Hezbollah into Israel, so the attention might backfire.

In most modern conflicts, the belligerents like to emphasise enemy attacks to help justify their own actions as defensive or retaliatory. Do you have any evidence that the Lebanese government/armed forces (distinct from Hezbollah) is launching attacks on Israel or planning to do so? Why do you think this applies to the situation?

The very basic definition of government includes having a monopoly on violence. The people in Beirut have no such monopoly over southern Lebanon and thus are mere figureheads, not a real “government” of that area. The true government is Hezbollah and they’ve been quite vocal.

Well, Hezbollah has now made press statements https://today.lorientlejour.com/article/1429613/hezbollah-spokesperson-confirms-fighting-along-border.html making this question singularly short lived.  This isn't the first "why haven't X responded/commented to Y?" question and they really ought to be asked only after that pattern has been well-established.  Which 24 hours doesn't really do.

It's all over the Arab language media. You can't listen to the news without hearing it.

Lebanon's government and Hezbollah are distinct entities.

Lebanese troops pull back from border as Israeli ground invasion looms

Lebanon's government urges international community for support amid Israel’s invasion


From these reports, it appears that Lebanon's government lacks both the military capability and the political will to defend its borders effectively. Consequently, they seem to be adopting a passive stance for several reasons:

Delegation to Hezbollah: The government may be quietly shifting the burden of border defense to Hezbollah, possibly feeling content with Hezbollah's capabilities as a deterrent.

Avoiding Pressure from the USA: If the Lebanese government were to assert itself more aggressively, it might invite pressure from the United States to dismantle Hezbollah as a non-state actor, which would be a significant loss for Lebanon's current power balance.

Lack of Regional Backers: Lebanon currently lacks significant backing in the region. Although Turkey's Erdogan recently declared support for Lebanon, his statement appears to be "all talk, no action," with no tangible support on the ground.


These factors suggest Lebanon is strategically opting for silence and reliance on Hezbollah to manage the ongoing crisis.

"USA tell them to get rid of it" - who said they will comply, and who said they even can comply?

Erdogan is not going to do anything to help Hezbollah/Iran due to their [still ongoing] disagreements about Syria/Assad https://www.middleeasteye.net/news/lebanon-hassan-nasrallah-assassination-why-turkey-silent Plus he still needs F-16 parts and there aren't anymore countries about to join NATO that he could use as a bargaining chip.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5CJYupx8okc

@IVFcomesfromthetip, This video is from the anti-Assad faction of Syria, which started a civil war to topple Bashar. We toppled Sheikh Hasina on the 5th of August; we didn't do it for benefiting NATO or Israel, and we didn't start a civil war. These guys are brainwashed stooges of the West.

Well, if India had backed Hasina with their air force and barrel bombed your neighborhood, you might feel differently.

@IVFcomesfromthetip, Incorrect and misplaced analogy. Russia didn't back Bashar first. These brainless idiots started an armed struggle, and then Bashar asked for Russian intervention. The same was the case of Iraq. LOL. Those brainless idiots invited the USA for invasion, and then the USA bombed them to oblivion. I wonder how many of those invitees survived the Anglo-US carpet bombings.

"Russia didn't back Bashar first". No Iran and Hezbollah did that. Then Soleimani travelled to Moscow to request air support. Which for a while came through Iranian air bases.

@IVFcomesfromthetip, Whatever the situation is, someone has to keep the big picture in their minds. Moral of the story: never seek help from snakes to get rid of a hyena.

Additionally, the ground incursions were a drop in the bucket, compared to the Israeli air incursions. Lebanon's government did protests those somewhat, as they were more visible, e.g. back in October 2023:

Israeli air raids hit a house in the southern village of Alma Shaab on Monday, according to Lebanese daily L’Orient Today. And Hezbollah announced the death of one of its fighters, its 49th casualty since October 7. [...]
Lebanese caretaker Prime Minister Najib Mikati told Sky News Arabia on Monday that he was demanding an end to “Israeli provocations” that might spiral into a regional war.
“The Lebanese people do not want war,” Mikati said. He did, however, add that he has “coordinated with international organisations to put in place an [emergency] plan in case war breaks out”.

There were probably more of those statements, but what Lebanon's government says generally receives little attention in Western media, as they are a small player in this affair.
The Lebanon's PM words sharpened in Sep 2024:

Lebanese caretaker Prime Minister, Najib Mikati, condemned what he described as a "destructive plan" of the Israeli entity which has been waging violent air raids on the south and east of Lebanon.
He stressed that the continued Israeli aggression on Lebanon is a war of extermination in every sense, and a plan aimed at destroying Lebanese villages and towns and eliminating all green spaces.

